# WebLogic: add a new custom authentication-providers via WLST throws a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I am trying to add a new custom authentication-provider with a WLST online-mode script but I get a class not found exception despite I can see my provider on the WL console.

**This is the situation:**

1. I have a JAR file, it contains a custom WebLogic authentication-provider.
2. The JAR is copied under the `user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/lib/` directory.
3. I can see the custom auth provider on the WL console, appears in the list: `Home > Security Realms > myrealm > Providers > new> Type`
4. I can add this custom provider by hand via WL Console.

But I need to automate this step so I have created a WLST script for this. The relevant part of the WLST is this:

```
# add a new authentication provider with name of MyCustomAuthProvider
cd('/SecurityConfiguration/' + _domainName + '/Realms/myrealm')
cmo.createAuthenticationProvider('MyCustomAuthProvider', 'aa.bb.cc.MyCustomAuthProvider')

cd('/SecurityConfiguration/' + _domainName + '/Realms/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/MyCustomAuthProvider')
cmo.setControlFlag('OPTIONAL')
    
# reorder authentication providers
...
```

**But this WLST throws the following exception:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aa.bb.cc.MyCustomAuthProvider
```

**So I did double-check to see whether the WL sees my custom auth provider:**

```
wls:/offline> connect('weblogic', 'weblogic12', 't3://localhost:7001')
cd('/SecurityConfiguration/myDomain/Realms/myrealm')
ls()
```

The list I got is exactly the same as I expected: my class is on the list. This is the reason why I can add it using the web console.

**This is the value of the AuthenticationProviderTypes:**

```
java.lang.String[com.bea.security.saml2.providers.SAML2IdentityAsserter,
aa.bb.cc.MyCustomAuthProvider,
eblogic.security.providers.authentication.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.CustomDBMSAuthenticator,
eblogic.security.providers.authentication.DefaultAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DefaultIdentityAsserter, 
eblogic.security.providers.authentication.IPlanetAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPX509IdentityAsserter,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NegotiateIdentityAsserter,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.NovellAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.OpenLDAPAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.OracleIdentityCloudIntegrator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.OracleInternetDirectoryAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.OracleUnifiedDirectoryAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.OracleVirtualDirectoryAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.ReadOnlySQLAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.SQLAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.authentication.VirtualUserAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.saml.SAMLAuthenticator,
weblogic.security.providers.saml.SAMLIdentityAsserterV2]
```

Everything looks perfect. But then why WLST throws a `class not found` exception while trying to create it?
This is crazy.

I have googled for this, but only the same issues I have found without a solution.

- [here](https://github.com/biemond/puppet/issues/57)

What I missed?

Comment: Your JAR file must be added to WLST's classpath. 
$DOMAIN_HOME/lib is used by servers start scripts and not with WLST.

Comment: The JAR is on the server classpath. Otherwise, my custom security provider just does not appear on the WL console.

Comment: But please, correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: the server classpath is not wlst classpath.
Your lib in the server classpath, so the console is able to deploy your custom security provider.
If you want to do so with WLST, you have to update your WLST script and update the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point oracle has changed from using `CLASSPATH` to `WLST_EXT_CLASSPATH` to set the classpath for WLST. Oracle doesn't seem to have done a great job of documenting that this is the right env variable to use though. I found it by digging through the various sh scripts that wlst.sh calls, but [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/DEVSP/aud.htm#DEVSP418) document for 12c refers to it, but seems to be the only place that it's mentioned.

I've tested this using 14.1.1 and a custom provider in the DOMAIN/lib/mbeantypes dir and it works (i.e. I can use WLST to configure a custom security provider as long as I set WLST_EXT_CLASSPATH first) but don't have 12c to test that it works there.

Answer (score 0):

I added my JAR to the WLST classpath, but this did not help.

- I changed the `CLASSPATH` variable because the `wlst.sh` executes a java command in the background so this standard variable must be considered. It did not work.
- I added the `-cp` JVM param manually to the java command that starts the WlST. It did not work.

**The only workaround that worked for me is that the following:**

- **for WL console**: copy the JAR that contains the custom authentication provider under `$ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/lib/` directory
- **for WLST**: copy the JAR to `$ORACLE_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/mbeantypes/`

The 2nd copy solved the `class not found issue` thrown by the WLST.

If you know a better, more standard way, please let me know.